# Save data of subquery into temporal table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ##TGJAE  
WHERE Asiento IN (SELECT SUBLEDGERVOUCHER  
                  FROM GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY AS GACE
                  INNER JOIN GENERALJOURNALENTRY AS GJE ON GJE.RECID = GACE.GENERALJOURNALENTRY 
                  WHERE POSTINGTYPE = 31
                  GROUP BY SUBLEDGERVOUCHER 
                  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1)
```

I want to save result of this query into temporal table. How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT * INTO <tablename> . . . `.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select * into #temptable` like so:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE FROM ##TGJAE  WHERE Asiento IN (SELECT 
SUBLEDGERVOUCHER  FROM GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY  AS GACE
INNER JOIN GENERALJOURNALENTRY AS GJE ON GJE.RECID = GACE.GENERALJOURNALENTRY 
WHERE POSTINGTYPE = 31
GROUP BY  SUBLEDGERVOUCHER HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 
)
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the temp table already exist and I think it doesn't.

Comment: @Icarus This will create the temptable if it doesnt exist, I suspect you know this as you have posted the same answer.

Comment: for some reason I thought I had read `insert into #temp select * from ...` in your answer. Apologies. I must have had too many beers at lunch time. +1

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT  *
INTO #TEMP_TABLE
FROM    ##TGJAE
WHERE   Asiento IN (
        SELECT  SUBLEDGERVOUCHER
        FROM    GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY AS GACE
                INNER JOIN GENERALJOURNALENTRY AS GJE ON GJE.RECID = GACE.GENERALJOURNALENTRY
        WHERE   POSTINGTYPE = 31
        GROUP BY SUBLEDGERVOUCHER
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * INTO ##YOURTEMPTABLE FROM  ##TGJAE  WHERE Asiento IN (SELECT SUBLEDGERVOUCHER  FROM GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY  AS GACE
INNER JOIN GENERALJOURNALENTRY AS GJE ON GJE.RECID = GACE.GENERALJOURNALENTRY WHERE POSTINGTYPE = 31
GROUP BY  SUBLEDGERVOUCHER HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 
)
```